# Ruby Singleton and Shotgun

Tags: ruby, sinatra, shotgun

Im starting with Ruby and our team leader sends us to learn Sinatra, reloading the application changes is been done by Shotgun, my problem now is that i have a Singleton entity
which i would love to keep states between request, but aparently Shotgun restarts is every request.

Any Help or Explanation on this would be apreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't expect anything about your application's state to be saved between requests at all (Shotgun or not) unless it is being saved in session data.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact reason for sessions.  HTTP is a stateless protocol and servers are not expected to preserve state between connections.

Comment: I understand this about http, but thats not the problem, im aware that HTTP is stateless, thats the reason why im using that singleton, to Store the data between the requests, even of diferent Users, so thats the reason why sessions doesn't work for me, also dont want now to store the data into database , the idea is just to kkep the data while the application is running, and that data should be stored into a sared object for the whole app, that seems to work without shoutgun, ( simple sinatra 'ruby app.rb' ), but when i come to reload shotgun it breaks

Comment: Regardless it's an unreliable method. In production you'll likely have more than one process running at the same time, and they won't be able to share between each other this way. If you restart your web server or it crashes and restarts itself, you'll lose the state. If you need to store persistant data for all users you need a persistant data store of some sort outside of your application (SQL, Redis, Memcached, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

For sessions to persist with Shotgun you need to set the key... Otherwise it is reset with every page load.

```
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, "yourKey"
```